# Why gradle publish task is not able to get secret token passed by Github action?

Tags: gradle, github-actions, cicd, github-packages

I have implemented GITHUB workflow actions to publish my Spring Boot app to GitHub Packages.

I have followed the Github [gradle ref](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-java-packages-with-gradle) but I'm getting **401 Unauthorized**
[image]

It seems that the github action is not able to pass env variables to let gradle task to get *GIT_CICD_TOKEN* by using *System.getenv("GIT_CICD_TOKEN")* .

My followed implementations:

***Step for publishing package*** on github packages:

```
- name: Publish package
  uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
  with:
      gradle-version: 8.5
      arguments: Publish
    env:
        GIT_CICD_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_CICD_TOKEN }}
```

Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = "https://maven.pkg.github.com/organization_name/repo_name"
            credentials {
                username = 'myUserName'
                password = System.getenv("GIT_CICD_TOKEN")
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bootJar
            groupId = 'com.xx'
            artifactId = 'appName'
            version = '0.0.1-XXXX-SNAPSHOT'
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**
I have tried to put token string value directly on password field and it worked fine.

Do you have any suggestions on it ?

Comment: Reading the readme file, it doesn't seem to me that this action allow you to substitute customizable env variables directly in the Gradle file. I would suggest using a [replace value](https://github.com/marketplace?category=&type=actions&verification=&query=replace+value) action from the marketplace before executing this step, to substitute the value in the gradle file before executing the publish action.

Comment: Now, if it's a GitHub PAT you're actually using here, it seems to be possible to informe one as an [action input](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-build-action/blob/5516b399405349a7d56e45a78a0bd4b3eaa62f9e/action.yml#L116). In that case, you should use `with:  github_token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}` when configuring the action. But it doesn't seem related the gradle file here, so it may not behave as you expect.

Comment: @GuiFalourd secrets.GIT_CICD_TOKEN is set and stored in secrets ENV. If you read the Github action doc and gradle the field is got from System.getenv

Comment: I didn't see the ref to Github Doc in your question, I just read the gradle action doc, my bad. For what I understand, shouldn't the env variable be named `GITHUB_TOKEN` instead of `GIT_CICD_TOKEN` in your workflow as well as in your Gradle file? e.g `GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_CICD_TOKEN }}` and `System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")`

Comment: @GuiFalourd I understood what you are telling me about GITHUB_TOKEN. Let me try it and I'm going to update my post.

Answer (score 1):

I understood that I can use the default GITHUB variables to publish the package without using Personal Access Token.

Let me post my workflow and build.gradle file that are working fine.

Ref GITHUB defaul Variables [link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables)

GITHUB **Publish-package** Workflow fixed :

```
name: Publish-package-on-GitHub-packages

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
        environment:
          description: Target environment
          required: true
          type: environment
          default: dev

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
        contents: read
        packages: write
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: packaging workflow  
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: |
          chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name : Get App Version
        id: get-app-version
        run: |
          echo "APP_VERSION_NAME=$(${{github.workspace}}/gradlew -q printAppVersionName)" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
      
      - name: Print App version
        id: print-app-version
        run: |
          echo "app version: ${{env.APP_VERSION_NAME}}"

      - name: Validate Gradle wrapper
        uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@v1

      - name: Publish package
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          gradle-version: 8.5
          arguments: Publish
        env:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Link to [GITHUB_TOKEN ref](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token)

**REMARK on GITHUB_TOKEN** and **GITHUB_ACTOR**

> At the start of each workflow job, GitHub automatically creates a
> unique **GITHUB_TOKEN** secret to use in your workflow. You can use the
> GITHUB_TOKEN to authenticate in the workflow job.

I recommended to check GITHUB_TOKEN's Workflow permissions at followed path

Action--> General --> Workflow permissions
In my case

[image]

**GITHUB_ACTOR**    The name of the person or app that initiated the workflow.

As written in the github documentation the ***permissions*** key specifies the access that the GITHUB_TOKEN secret will allow.

***build.gradle*** 8.5 version

```
        plugins {
            id 'maven-publish'
            id 'java'
            id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
            id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
        }
        
        ext {
            group = 'com.xx'
            name = 'app_name'
            version = '0.0.1-feature_name-SNAPSHOT'
        }
        
        
        java {
            sourceCompatibility = '17'
        }
        
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        
        dependencies {
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
            testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        }

        task printAppVersionName {
        setSkipBootRun();
        println project.ext.version
    }
    
        def setSkipBootRun() {
        def value = hasProperty('inputSkipBootRun') ? inputSkipBootRun : false;
        project.ext.skipBootRun = value;
    
        }
        
        tasks.named('test') {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
        
        
        publishing {
            repositories {
                maven {
                    name = "GitHubPackages"
                    url = "https://maven.pkg.github.com/org_name/repo_name"
                    credentials {
                        username = System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")
                        password = System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
                    }
                }
            }
        
            publications {
                maven(MavenPublication) {
                    artifact bootJar
                    groupId = project.ext.group
                    artifactId = project.ext.name
                    version = project.ext.version
                }
            }
        }
```